# Image icon on tabs appear very small even though I'm using the correct dimensions (hdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi ...)

Tags: java, android, tabs

I followed the guidelines on the Google developer page to creat these 5 folders and filled them with icons of the correct dimensions:

[image]

I created my tabs using a `TabHost` like so:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.homeicon));
    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec2.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.startachainwhite48dp));
    TabHost.TabSpec spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec3.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.joinachainwhite48dp));
    TabHost.TabSpec spec4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4");
    spec4.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    spec4.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.viewchainswhite48dp));
    TabHost.TabSpec spec5 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab5");
    spec5.setContent(R.id.tab5);
    spec5.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profilewhite48dp));

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);
    tabHost.addTab(spec4);
    tabHost.addTab(spec5);
```

But for some reason the icons on my tabs (at the bottom) show up tiny

[image]

Does anybody have an explanation/solution for this? I feel like I have made a silly mistake somewhere - will post xml layout if needed. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It may be worth mentioning that the getDrawable() method I'm using in the above code is deprecated (API 22)

EDIT2: Full XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#FF86B39A"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.sv_laptop03.myapp.Profile">

        <TabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerview"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: show your XMLs, 'cos that where I'd suspect culprit lurking....

Comment: as for deprecated method, you should use `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)` instead

Comment: Posted the XML layout, and thanks.

Comment: Hi @eyesenberg did you solve this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that every thing will looks as you expected, just add images into the `xxxhdpi` folder and be sure that they are 192x192 px.

By this method you let the OpenGL convert the image to what device the app is running on and that also give you the ability to resize your images without losing any details.

Hope this will help you.
Reference here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Yes I have done that already using that link. This is the result for me

Comment: remove all the other resources from the other folders except the xxxhdpi :)
and then try to set a specific min width and min height :)

Comment: I thought the whole point of doing it this way is that your icon's get scaled to the appropriate size automatically without having to scale them yourself

Comment: But if you dont some limits you will end up with the same result as before .. the main idea here is to make your app as light as possible ..